# Read an array from a file until 0 is encountered

Tags: c, file

The array number of elements is unknown

The file input is:
2 3 4 5 8 0

The array will have:
2 3 4 5 8

```
int read(FILE *in,int a[])
{
int i = 0;
int temp; 
while(fscanf(in, "%d", &temp) != EOF)
    {
        a[i++] = temp;
    }

return i;
}
```

This code returns 0 so it's not working;

Comment: When I input 2 3 4 5 8 0 the output returns only 5 8 0

Comment: I assume `a[]` is not initialized before calling this function? (Not that there would be a sane way to initialize it anyway...)

Answer (score 2):

in your for loop you are reading `a[i]` before you access it. However if you use fscanf it is good to check if the end of file is reached using EOF. I find elegant using this approach:

```
int read(FILE *in,int a[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int temp; 
    while(fscanf(in, "%d", &temp) != EOF){
        a[i++] = temp;
    }

    return i;
}
```

The value of EOF returned by fscanf is -1 and not 0. In the case of an input failure, before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

EDIT:

Although this could be a good approach, as Jonathan pointed out in his comment, if you have a literal in your text file the fscanf will never reach EOF keeping incrementing `i` and eventually crashing the program.

This is the best approach to solve the problem:

```
while(fscanf(in, "%d", &temp) == 1){

 }
```

Checking the correct number of conversions (one in this example) guarantees to exit the loop correctly.

Comment: Close, but that will fail horribly if you type `a` as an input.  You should almost always check that you got the correct number of conversions, which is 1 in this example: `while (fscanf(in, "%d", &temp) == 1) { …`, stopping when the number is wrong.

Comment: I see, good point, I'll edit my answer. Although I don't understand this statement "that will fail horribly if you type a as an input". What you mean?

Comment: Try it and see.  You won't get EOF, but you will keep incrementing `i` and eventually write out of bounds of the array `a`.  This usually crashes your program.

Comment: I set up a small program to test it and it works given a text file with a few numbers. Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/nbasakuragi/125cc5e8d13ee814afc0 I debug it and it reaches EOF exiting correctly. I still see the value of comparing the correct number of conversions but I don't how it won't get EOF

Comment: ok I see what you mean now. I put a char in the text file and it will never reach EOF. Thanks for pointing this out :-)

Comment: @GiovanniCampo that's exactly the same problem in the other answer.

Comment: print out the value of a[i]?

Comment: @GiovanniCampo this code returns 0 my input is:1 5 7 8 12 0

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to do. The index i that returns from the function is the number of read elements in your file. have u debugged it? are u allocating the array `a[]` correctly? can you see the number being allocated into `a`?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple

```
int readDataFromFile(FILE *in, int *a, size_t size)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((i < size) && (fscanf(in, "%d", &a[i]) == 1) && (a[i] != 0))
     {
        i += 1;
     }
    return (a[i] == 0) ? i : SOME_INVALID_VALUE_LIKE_MINUS_1;
}
```

Now suppose your file's path is `/myfile/path/file.data`, then `main()` could look like this

```
int main(void)
{
    int    array[100];
    int    result;
    size_t size;
    FILE  *file;

    file = fopen("/myfile/path/file.data", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open the file for reading\n");
        return -1;
     }
    size   = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    result = readDataFromFile(file, array, size);
    /* do something with `result' and `array' */
    return 0;
}
```

Your code is very unsafe, because you do no bound checking and you don't check if the value was read.

Also, don't use that name for a function, first of all it's a standard function, and also it's not very descriptive of what the function does.

Comment: I didn't use that name actually I put that name to be more specific

Comment: I need to solve this problem without using pointers & memory allocation stuff

Comment: @Comrade57, Ok, please don't post parts of the code by **typing** it in the editor, because the problem might not be copied properly.

Comment: So when you call the function do it like this, suppose that the file is already open and you are certain of that, then `int array[100]; int result; result = readData(file, array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));`.

Comment: You say "It's very simple" and then you post the most complicated possible way to do it?

Comment: @immibis why is this way complicated? it's safe and simple.

Comment: You are right, it was unreadable and I hate that too, and i fixed it, not because you said or because of the downvotes but because it made me uncomfortable with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code fails is that you *read* from `a[i]` before writing to it. So, if there's a zero in `a[i]`, your loop ends before encountering a zero in your file. This is the lucky case, if you're unlucky, all valid elements of `a[]` are non-zero, and you have out-of-bounds array access.

```
int read(FILE *in,int a[])
{
  int i = 0;
  int temp = 0;
  do
  {
    fscanf(in,"%d ",&temp);
    if (!temp)
      break;
    a[i++] = temp;
    temp = 0;
  } while (1);
  return i;
}
```

Comment: terrible mistake, can you see it?

Comment: Ignoring the return value of `fscanf()` is potential undefined behavior, coding like that your programs will no be very robust, you need to check that `fscanf()` returned `1` before accessing `temp` and also, there is absolutely no need to use the confising `break`.

Comment: @iharob: Nope! It's all good. Notice the (re)initialization of `temp = 0`. If `fscanf()` matches no input, `temp == 0` and the loop ends without writing to `a[i]`.

Comment: Ok, what if you reach the end of the file? and worst, what if there is no more space in the array? And I really fail to understand why so many programmers use `break` that way, what is the `while` control condition for? is it an ornament?

Comment: @iharob: If the end of file is reached, `temp` stays zero, the loop ends. If the file contains more non-zero numbers than the array can hold, that's outside of the original question.

Comment: I don't think so... If the end of file is reached your loop will continue looping, if there is no `0` in the file for example.

Comment: also you have a typo, there shouldn't be a space after `%d` in the format string